# Getting error Authentication with Apple Developer Portal failed while Expo build:ios

Tags: ios, react-native, expo

I have developed a mobile application using Expo react native. I exported .apk and.aab easily. Now, I am unable to export the .ipa file through Expo CLI and getting error "Authentication with Apple Developer Portal failed". I have an Apple developer id that has '**manager rights**'.

Can someone help out me in this matter? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

1. Basically, it wants you to login in Apple Developer Portal but you
   shouldn't sign into the platform. You can just type 'n' when it asks
   the developer account.
2. Then normal procedure will keep on and you will get the IPA file
   after the build.

You can also try for expo build:ios -c to generate an ipa

If you are creating IPA for the first time, you need to upload the
certificates from developer account. You can find the procedures
down below.

[Expo First Time Build](https://docs.expo.io/distribution/building-standalone-apps/)